# SQL Error 1193 when attempting to import database

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, runtime-error, kali-linux

So I've downloaded a huge database from the internet and I'm trying to import it using `mysql -t < data_dump.sql`
After running this, I get the following output:
`ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 5: Unknown system variable 'statement_timeout'`

I tried doing this with another SQL file previously, and it worked just fine. Sorry if this is a really easy problem to fix, I'm not very experienced with SQL.

Comment: Are you trying to import a postgresql dump by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have this error because you are trying to import the .sql file from an other database engine.If you want to use the .sql file you need to convert the dump file from postgre (syntax-format ) to mysql (syntax-format).
For more help check [here](https://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php)